# Yocto core-image-x11 can't run Qt6 QML app

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto, qt6

this is my yocto configuration:

```
Build Configuration:

BB_VERSION           = "2.2.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "raspberrypi3"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "4.1.4"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa7 neon vfpv4 thumb callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "langdale:3e95f268ce04b49ba6731fd4bbc53b1693c21963"
meta-raspberrypi     = "langdale:8e3cbfa598de106a78d9a9e27aa25ded51416896"
meta-oe              
meta-multimedia      
meta-networking      
meta-python          = "langdale:cbbaa82238cd60f08c9b9cb58dde59d5f9318c7b"
meta-qt6             = "6.5:a65fb409f4469c087ae3e23ee80fbb2531f1856e"
meta-app             = "<unknown>:<unknown>"
```

I bitbake core-image-x11 for Raspberry Pi 3 but when I launch my Qt6 QML app on the target, I get this error:

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
qt.qpa.plugin: From 6.5.0, xcb-cursor0 or libxcb-cursor0 is needed to load the Qt xcb platform plugin
```

On my target, I can't find any file called "*cursor0*", I can only find files:

```
/usr/lib/libxcb-cursor.so.0
/usr/lib/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
/usr/lib/libXcursor.so.1
/usr/lib/libxcb-cursor.so.0.0.0
```

What can I do to be able to launch my Qt6 QML app on Raspberry Pi 3?